# Latex Error : File "extsizes.sty" not found

Tags: miktex, texmaker

While running the latex template for Nanoscale Journal, I face the following error:

> Latex Error : File"extsizes.sty" not found

What is the reason and how can it be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the package `extsizes` in order to compile your document.

I'll suppose that your TeX distribution doesn't download package when needed.
What you can do is to download it on [CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/extsizes) and install it.

According to the comment made by the OP, MiKTeX is used. Then MiKTeX have a [package manager](http://docs.miktex.org/manual/pkgmgt.html).

Comment: Which Tex distribution includes this package. Miktex 2.9 is the current installation.

Comment: @user87834 : MikTeX should use it. You can use this link to see how to install it with the package manager: http://docs.miktex.org/manual/pkgmgt.html